# placeholder function

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback, contentplaceholder

I have a table inside a placeholder. when i click a `go` button the table becomes visible. However when i click on a radiobutton list with autopostback property set to true, the table within that placeholder dissapears. Is there any way to make the table within that placeholder permanent once i have made it visible thru the `go` button?

how to make a table within a placeholder visible?? 
I am using

```
placeholder1.visible = true;
table1.visible = true;
```

but still its not showing up.. do i need to use any other property.? please help..

Comment: Can you elaborate working of "go" button? will this button do a postback or change the visibility of table via javascript?

Comment: the go button is like an enter. u click it, and the table within the placeholder gets created and gets displayed.but on pressing anyother button, the table vanishes.. i have to click the go button once again to bring back the table.no, the go button doesnt have a postback activated. it creates a table,fills it up with values from database and displays it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the visible state of the table is persisted through post back and restored when the page renders again.

Comment: how do i ensure that? y does the table within the placeholder vanish when i dont write anything to make it invisible explicitly. ?how do i make the table permanent/??